# Showing that a function is surjective (onto)?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

For example : $F:\Bbb R\rightarrow\Bbb R$ defined by $F(x) = \frac{2x+1}{3}$

I let $F(x)=Y$ which gives $Y=\frac{2x+1}{3}$ then simplify and solve for $x$ , what I have at the end is $x=\frac{3Y-1}{2}$ , now I don't get how does this prove that the function is onto ?

Comment: Because for that value $Y$ you have found an $x$ for which $F(x)=y$.

Comment: try to show that the range is the subset of the domain then the function is surjective

Comment: For any $y$, you've found an $x$ so that $F(x) = y$, and that $x$ is $\frac{3y-1}{2}$.

Comment: $f:\mathbb{A} \to \mathbb{B}$ is surjective iff for each element $b$ from the codomaind $B$ (in your case $A = B = \mathbb{R}$ there is an element $a$ in the domain $A$. In other words, each $b\in B$ has a coimage, or $\forall b \in B: \exists a \in A f(a) = b$.

Comment: Can someone show me an example where a function is not onto please

Comment: $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, f(x) = x^2$ is **not onto**, you can easily confirm that $x^2 \geq 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, therefore no negative element will have a coimage. That is for $y\in \mathbb{R}, y<0, \not\exists x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x) = x^2= y$.

Comment: $f(x)=0$ is not onto, in fact the only value it hits is zero.

Comment: @GregoryGrant its basically the constant function

Comment: @Rememberme Yes, well... *a* constant function anyway.  I believe counter-examples should always be as simple as possible.

Comment: @GregoryGrant I agree, not sure, why $f(x)=x^2$ came to my mind as the first candidate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function $f$ from $A$ to $B$ is called *onto*, if and only if for every element b $\in B$, there is an element $a \in A$ with $f(a) = b$.

In other words, proving a function is *onto* comes down to showing that for every element in the codomain there **exists** an element in the domain which maps to it. Thus, it is an **existence** proof.

By picking an arbitrary $y$, you are finding a possible candidate for a domain element. Once you substitute it in the function and obtain $y$, an element in the codomain, you have demonstrated that it is a suitable domain element.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is nicely answered already, but just to restate the facts and maybe give another point of view.

Let $A,B$ be a set (e.g. $A=B= \mathbb{R}$). Then *cartesian product* $\times$ of $A,B$ is defined as

$$
A\times B = \{(a,b): a \in A, b \in B\}
$$

Then a relation $R$ is defined as $R\subseteq A\times B$. So, basically a set of ordered pairs. A function (I think the most common definition) is as follows

$f:A\to B$ is *function* if $f$ is relation ($f\subseteq A\times B$) such that for every $a \in A$ there is exactly one $b\in B$ such that $(a,b) \in f$.

The last expression $(a,b) \in f$ can be rewritten in many different ways, e.g. $(a,b) \in f \leftrightarrow a f b$ or most commonly $f(a) = b$.

There is also **geometrical visualization** (of relation in general):

**Ex.1**
Imagine $f \subseteq \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N} = \{(n, n): n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, then you can visualize as follows

\begin{align}
&f\\
1 &\mapsto 1\\
2 &\mapsto 2\\
&\vdots\\
n &\mapsto n\\
&\vdots
\end{align}

The question, whether $f$ is surjective (you can read the definition in other answers/comments) is now following:

*Is there an arrow pointing to each number on the right?*

The answer to **Ex.1** is yes, there is.

**Ex.2** $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}, f(n) = 2n$ and let us *draw it*
\begin{align}
&f\\
  &\hphantom{1 \mapsto} 1\\
1 &\mapsto 2\\
  &\phantom{3 \mapsto} 3\\
2 &\mapsto 4\\
&\vdots\\
n &\mapsto 2n\\
&\vdots
\end{align}

As you can see, there are **no** arrows pointing to odd numbers on the right side. So $f$ from **Ex.2** is not surjective.

**Of course** this is nice only for *discrete* examples (or even finite one). But this is not advised as proof. This is merely a try to help you imagine, what **onto** means.