# How does this prove that the ring homomorphism is surjective?

Tags: ring-theory

The course notes on rings have the below lemma

> Let $R$ be a ring and $I$ a two sided ideal. Define $\pi : R \rightarrow R/I$ by $\pi(r)=r+I$. Then $\pi$ is a surjective ring map and ker $\pi=I$.

Proving that $\pi$ is a homomorphism is straightforward, but I don't quite understand their proof of surjectivity, which I've typed below:

> If $r+I \in R/I$, then $\pi (r)=r+I$, and hence $\pi$ is surjective.

If $\pi$ is defined to be the $\pi(r)=r+I$, then why did they need to say "then $\pi(r)=r+I"$? It's almost as if they concluded that, but it was a definition in the first place!

The below is my understanding of what they were trying to say, is this correct?

> $R/I$ is, by definition of the quotient, $r+I$ for all $r, I\in R$. But this is exactly the map of $\pi(r)$, so every single element under the mapping $\pi$ has a corresponding element in $R$. In other words, $\pi$ is a surjective map.

I also would like to know, does this not mean that $\pi$ is bijective? Or does the whole idea of 'modulo' when working with quotients break the uniqueness required for bijectivity?

Comment: Let $\pi:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}/(7)\mathbb{Z}, m\mapsto m+(7)\mathbb{Z}$. Then, $\pi(5)=\pi(12)$, because $12-5=7\in(7)\mathbb{Z}$, so $\pi$ is not injective.

Comment: To prove, that any map is surjective you need to find preimage for all the elements from the codomain ([see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1275540/112628)). So, you take arbitrary element form $R/I$, that element looks like $r+I$ and what is its preimage? Well, in this case it is really straightforward, that the preimage is $r$, because $\pi(r) = r+I$.

Comment: You have a mistake in the bit you wrote, $I$ is already fixed, so do not write $I \in R$, not to mention, that it is not true in general. $I \subseteq R$. The $I \in R$ would make sense, only if $I$ would be generated by one element, $I =  \{ra, r \in R, a \text{ fixed}\}$. But I would still avoid this notation, and would use something like this $(a) =  \{ra, r \in R, a \text{ fixed}\}$, so $(a)\notin R$ but $a \in R$. Bear in mind, that the notation $(a)$ is not good for one-sided ideals, better would be $Ra =\{ra, r \in R, a \text{ fixed}\}$ (for left ideal, and similarly for right one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your seem to have the main idea, but let me try to clarify.

The map $\pi : R \to R/I$ is given by $\pi(r) = r + I$. In order to show $\pi$ is surjective, we need to show that given any element $ y \in R/I$, there exists an element $x \in R$ such that $\pi(x) = y$ (this is just the definition of surjectivity of a map of sets). Now, as $R/I = \{r + I \mid r \in R\}$, we can write $y$ as $a + I$ for some $a \in R$. So we need to show that there is $x \in R$ such that $\pi(x) = a + I$. As $\pi(x) = x + I$ by definition of the map $\pi$, we can rewrite the equation as $x + I = a + I$. One way to guarantee this equation holds true is to choose $x = a$; then we have $\pi(x) = \pi(a) = a + I = y$. So for any element $y \in R/I$, we have shown that there is $x \in R$ such that $\pi(x) = y$, therefore $\pi$ is surjective.

A map between sets is bijective if it is surjective and injective. The map $\pi$ is surjective, but unless $I$ is the trivial ideal (i.e. $I = \{0\}$), $\pi$ is not injective. Recall, a map $f : X \to Y$ is said to be injective if for all $x_1, x_2 \in X$, $x_1 \neq x_2$, $f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$. To see that $\pi : R \to R/I$ is not injective if $I \neq \{0\}$, note that $I$ contains at least two elements (any ideal contains $0$ and as $I \neq \{0\}$, it must contain another element). Let $r_1, r_2 \in I$, $r_1 \neq r_2$; note that $I \subseteq R$, so $r_1, r_2 \in R$. Then $\pi(r_1) = r_1 + I = I$ (as $r_1 \in I$) and $\pi(r_2) = r_2 + I = I$ (as $r_2 \in I$); that is, $\pi(r_1) = \pi(r_2)$. Therefore, $\pi$ is not injective, so $\pi$ is not bijective.